# Can someone explain this Java ThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, threadpool

I've created a FixedThreadPool for a 1000 threads. 
Each individual thread needs to increment a global counter by one. 
So actually this is part of a programming assignment, I dont want the straight up answer, and i've already spend a few hours on this problem.

So some advice would be greatly appreciated. So this is my code :

```
public class ThreadSpawner {
private int sum = 0;
public static void main(String[] args){
    ThreadSpawner ts = new ThreadSpawner();
    ts.doWork();

}

public void doWork(){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);     
    for(int i =0;i<1000;i++){
        executor.execute(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Value: " + sum + Thread.currentThread());
                counter();
                }

            public synchronized void counter(){
                sum++;
            }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The assignment specifically asks this : *"Write a program that launches 1,000 threads. Each thread adds 1 to a variable sum
that initially is 0. Define an Integer wrapper object to hold sum. Run the program with and without
synchronization to see its effect.
You can use newFixedThreadPool() to create a fixed number of threads in the pool.*"

I've tried it already with a separate runnable taskClass for the threads. however I cant find a way to edit the sum variable from within the threads.

This inner thread way Im using now at least shows somewhat correct behaviour.

Could anyone provide some insights as to what would be a more correct way to adress such a problem ?

- I am also unsure as to how and where implement the synchronization keyword to correctly force the threads to synchronize.

Kind regards!
Sietze

Comment: "Define an Integer wrapper object to hold sum" Well for starters, you haven't done that. Write a class which wraps a volatile int which has a synchronized `increment` method.

Comment: What do you mean "however I cant find a way to edit the sum variable from within the threads."? This code changes `sum`.

Comment: Note: In any _real_ program, the number of threads in the thread pool would be much smaller than the number of tasks that are submitted to the thread pool.  The entire reason for pooling threads is to re-use them, but there is no effective re-use if the number of threads equals the number of tasks.

Comment: Don't do I/O (i.e., don't call `System.out.println(...)`) from within your threads.  I/O will block the caller for a significant amount of time, and the `println` function is `synchronized`.  Both of those things will profoundly influence the execution order of your threads---maybe in a way that hides what the exercise is supposed to teach you.

Comment: P.S.: Don't start a fight with your teacher over this, but there's no reason for this program to have a thousand threads.  Two threads that each increment the variable 500 times (or better yet, 5,000,000 times) will either do "the right thing" or not depending on whether they are correctly synchronized or not.

Comment: @Michael I didn't do that, because I failed to see how exactly the Integer wrapper would be able to force synchronized behaviour ?

Comment: I understand the assignment is purely academic and in professional programming such a thread program would probably be nonsense.

Comment: because if the increment method is synchronized then each thread can only increment it one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I've come a solution from the author. I've its considered bad practice to post such solutions here I'll remove it.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Exercise30_04 {
  private int sum = new Integer(0);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exercise30_04 test = new Exercise30_04();
    System.out.println("What is sum ? " + test.sum);
  }

  public Exercise30_04() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      executor.execute(new SumTask());
    }

    executor.shutdown();

    while(!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }
  }

  class SumTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      sum++;
//      int value = sum.intValue() + 1;
//      sum = new Integer(value);
    }
  }
}
```

This solution seems to run correct result of 1000 without the synchronized keyword.

So would it make sense to implement the synchronized keyword here ? 
Personally I've placed it on the run method of the runnable class.

Anyway thanks all for response.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to self-answer a question, but once again, the question said to implement a wrapper class and you haven't, so don't expect full marks